# Remote into headless Unit

Tags: 20.04, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, headless

So when I try to remote in via TightVNC I just get a black screen, the port was open and after some troubleshooting I figured it had to be that screen sharing was disabled in preferences. That's fine, but the only ways I could fine to enable it are via the GUI. It is a headless unit however, and I have no way to hook it up to a screen. I am able to SSH into but that limits me to the terminal and I'd like full remote desktop control. When using 'gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled true' I get "enabled key not found" or something along those lines. I'm at a loss here, any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is the machine you are trying to VNC into running Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? If it's the latter, then there is no desktop environment installed by default.

Comment: It's ubuntu desktop

Comment: If you are running vncserver you can run `vncserver :0 -geometry 1440x900` on the server side.  It's what I use.  Then on the client side I use Remmina and set to VNC.